# Connection timeout on identification

Tags: thrift, cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I am trying to connect to my new cadence server (for this test, it's running in a Kubernetes cluster and I have a port-forward set up), but I am getting a `Connection timeout on identification` error.

This is the code I am using to connect

```
    WorkflowClient workflowClient = WorkflowClient.newInstance(
        new WorkflowServiceTChannel(ClientOptions.newBuilder()
            .setHost("localhost")
            .setPort(7933)
            .build()),
        WorkflowClientOptions.newBuilder().setDomain("test-domain").build());

    ConjunctionWorkflow conjunctionWorkflow = workflowClient.newWorkflowStub(ConjunctionWorkflow.class);
    conjunctionWorkflow.runConjunction();
```

This is the error message

```
org.apache.thrift.TException: Rpc error:<ErrorResponse id=-1 errorType=NetworkError message=Connection timeout on identification: localhost/127.0.0.1:7933/cadence-frontend::WorkflowService::StartWorkflowExecution>
    at com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel.throwOnRpcError(WorkflowServiceTChannel.java:346)
    at com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel.doRemoteCall(WorkflowServiceTChannel.java:317)
    at com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel.startWorkflowExecution(WorkflowServiceTChannel.java:646)
    at com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel.lambda$StartWorkflowExecution$9(WorkflowServiceTChannel.java:634)
    at com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel.measureRemoteCallWithTags(WorkflowServiceTChannel.java:375)
    at com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel.measureRemoteCall(WorkflowServiceTChannel.java:363)
    at com.uber.cadence.serviceclient.WorkflowServiceTChannel.StartWorkflowExecution(WorkflowServiceTChannel.java:633)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.external.GenericWorkflowClientExternalImpl.lambda$startWorkflowInternal$0(GenericWorkflowClientExternalImpl.java:122)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.common.RpcRetryer.retryWithResult(RpcRetryer.java:135)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.external.GenericWorkflowClientExternalImpl.startWorkflowInternal(GenericWorkflowClientExternalImpl.java:121)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.external.GenericWorkflowClientExternalImpl.startWorkflow(GenericWorkflowClientExternalImpl.java:82)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.sync.WorkflowStubImpl.startWithOptions(WorkflowStubImpl.java:133)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.sync.WorkflowStubImpl.start(WorkflowStubImpl.java:217)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.sync.WorkflowInvocationHandler.startWorkflow(WorkflowInvocationHandler.java:177)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.sync.WorkflowInvocationHandler.access$400(WorkflowInvocationHandler.java:43)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.sync.WorkflowInvocationHandler$SyncWorkflowInvocationHandler.startWorkflow(WorkflowInvocationHandler.java:288)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.sync.WorkflowInvocationHandler$SyncWorkflowInvocationHandler.invoke(WorkflowInvocationHandler.java:248)
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.sync.WorkflowInvocationHandler.invoke(WorkflowInvocationHandler.java:164)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy4.runConjunction(Unknown Source)
    at io.nsesi.starlux.playground.cadenceplayground.RunStartSingleWorkflow.main(RunStartSingleWorkflow.java:20)
```

Googling hasn't given me any info on this, what am I missing?